# How do I register a generic type in MVVMCross

Tags: c#, generics, mvvmcross

I have an interface defined as follows:

```
public interface ISerializationStrategy<T>
```

and also a generic implementation:

```
    public class SerializationStrategy<T> : Core.Strategies.ISerializationStrategy<T>
```

When I register this in the IOC do I have to do the following for each type:

```
Mvx.RegisterType<ISerializationStrategy<IdentityProvider>,SerializationStrategy<IdentityProvider>>();
... each type
```

Or is there a way to register an open generic (I think thats what it's called). The following doesn't work:

```
Mvx.RegisterSingleton(typeof (ISerializationStrategy<>),typeof (SerializationStrategy<>));
```

Thanks

Ross

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default IoC container in MvvmCross is https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/blob/v3.1/CrossCore/Cirrious.CrossCore/IoC/MvxSimpleIoCContainer.cs

It maintains a dictionary of service types (interfaces) to `resolvers` (objects which implement `IResolver`)

The `IResolver`'s currently supported only knows about how to supply actual types - not generic families of types. So this default IoC container and its resolvers cannot currently serve multiple instances in the way you request.

---

If you wanted to, you could extend or replace MvvmCross's default IoC Container with one that knows about families of types - the interface you'd need to support is https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/blob/v3.1/CrossCore/Cirrious.CrossCore/IoC/IMvxIoCProvider.cs and the https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/blob/v3.1/CrossCore/Cirrious.CrossCore/IoC/MvxSimpleIoCContainer.cs **might** be useful for you as a base class.

---

Alternatively, you could continue to use the `MvxSimpleIoCContainer` service and could register a non-generic service to supply your types at runtime - e.g. something with an interface:

```
public interface ISerializationStrategyFactory 
{
     ISerializationStrategy<T> CreateFactory<T>();
}
```

From the code in your question, I think this could be implemented just by:

```
public class SerializationStrategyFactory : ISerializationStrategyFactory 
{
     public ISerializationStrategy<T> CreateFactory<T>()
     {
         return new SerializationStrategy<T>();
     }
}
```

---

As one final alternative you could also use some reflection and a `foreach` loop to determine which classes to use in your current multiple calls to: `Mvx.RegisterType<ISerializationStrategy<IdentityProvider>,SerializationStrategy<IdentityProvider>>();`

Comment: I take it the final option (reflection) wouldn't work with mono touch? I really like the factory option so I thinkg thats what I will do! Thanks Stuart

Answer (score 1):

I had the same question and ended registering each type that I needed.

```
private static IEnumerable<Type> MyTypes
{
  get
  {
    //Return concrete types, NOT interfaces
    yield return typeof(MyType<Arg1>);
    yield return typeof(MyType<Arg2>);
    //...
  }
}

public override void Initialize()
{
  base.Initialize();
  MyTypes.AsInterfaces().RegisterAsLazySingleton();
}
```

If you don't do it, you may have an issue on iOS when you construct a generic type from an interface and the concrete generic type is never referenced anywhere with that type parameter.

See [Xamarin Limited Generics Support](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/advanced_topics/limitations/)